# Why default works but alt don't?

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, gnu-make, xelatex

This is `doc.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

And this is `Makefile`

```
export SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 
export FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 

default:
    SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 xelatex doc.tex
    md5 doc.pdf

alt:
    xelatex doc.tex
    md5 doc.pdf
```

Why default works but alt don't?

This is the output

```
$ make
SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 xelatex doc.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./doc.aux)
[1] (./doc.aux) )
Output written on doc.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on doc.log.
md5 doc.pdf
MD5 (doc.pdf) = f4fe5b98bcf0f7709f6b83e31c4413f6
```

And

```
$ make alt
xelatex doc.tex
xelatex: fatal: invalid epoch-seconds-timezone value for environment variable $SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH: 0 .
make: *** [alt] Error 1
```

I'm running this on macOS terminal, guess same will happen on Linux.

Comment: Does `xelatex doc.tex` work on the command line? If not, then this problem has nothing to do with makefiles.

Comment: Yes, `xelatex`is a command line tool. And I think same happens with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Probably the question will be more on topic at https://tex.stackexchange.com/.